# Algorithm for find polygons on a 2d grid

Tags: c#, algorithm, grid, 2d, polygons

I'm not really good in maths, so I'm having really hard times to find an algorithm do this:

- i have a grid like this: (8x8) [GRID 8x8](http://s9.postimg.org/nylepfahb/Immagine.jpg)

I'm trying to find an alghorithm that help me to find the red polygon and after that, all the cell inside this polygon will be red.

At this moment i'm using C# and i have a multi-dimensional array with the grid colour map, so i have to work on it; but i don't know what i can do.

```
private Color[,] mapColor;
mapColor= new Color[8, 8];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "to find the red polygon and after that, all the cell inside this polygon will be red."
It's unclear what are you asking really. What cells are you talking about? And what is "polygon"? Do you mean a square polygon or a triangular one?

Comment: i'm sorry, i need to find a square polygon. The cells are 64, as you can see  from the image, and all of this cells have one color. So the operation are two: find the square polygons from all connected cell(in this case red). is it more clear now? sorry for my bad english

Comment: i found an example! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7GM7N0dlGs

Comment: Not really tbh :) So by the "cell" you mean the same thing as "square polygon"? Do you want to find all the cells with the same color, that are connected to each other? I believe you're after some kind of flooding alghoritm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: yes, i already know this "flood fill", but it can work if i already know that all the cells with the same color, that are connected to each other form a square polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not too clear, and I couldn't see the image (blocked by my firewall). What I understand is that you want to follow all possible paths starting from a red cell and trying to find a polygon.

If it is the question, sounds like a Graph problem. You'll problably solve it using a BFS (Breadth First Search) algorithm, thinking in the Grid as a Graph (each cell can have like 8 edges - if you want to consider diagonal ways -  or 4 edges if you want to consider only up/down and left/right directions).

BFS will return the shortest path. If you want all possible paths, you should use DFS (Depth First Search) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the bitmap every 64 pixels and then call a function that checks nearby pixels to confirm it has found a red square.  As long as there's high contrast in the image like you have, it shouldn't be too hard to find the places inordinately biased towards red.

e.g.

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> PossibleCoords = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>();

for(int i = 0; i < Bitmap.Width/64; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < Bitmap.Height/64)
    {
        if(Bitmap.GetPixel(i*64, j*64).R > 200)
        {
            KeyValuePair<int, int> temp = new KeyValuePair<int, int>();
            KeyValuePair.Key = i*64;
            KeyValuePair.Value = j*64;
            PossibleCoords.Add(temp);
        }
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < PossibleCoords.Count; i++)
{
    SampleAdjacentPixelsToConfirm(PossibleCoords[i]);
}
```

To take a sample, I'd check if the ratio of red to the other colors is high if I were after high precision.